# Loading jquery locally

Tags: jquery

Is there another way than loading jquery through the link:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

But when I use wp_enqueue_script("jquery") the local wordpress homepage (with xampp) returns the value NULL

Comment: Do you have any other plugin which deque the jquery? Or ay caching plugin?

Comment: Yes got three other Plugins where wp_enqueue_script('jquery') is part of the code. So I use it the forth time for my new plugin. What can I do?

Comment: It does not matter how much time the script enqueue. WordPress load it only once. Try by deactivating all of other plugins temporary.

Comment: your question is not very clear. wordpress do not load jquery from any CDN, and I have no idea what `NULL` are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems like you should be able to just call the function and have it load the script, it's slightly more complicated. Instead, scripts need to be registered and enqueued inside a hook, so they're loaded in the right order.

To get jQuery loaded on the front end of your theme wrap the function call inside a callback for the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. One way is to add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () { wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); } );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes for more info.

Comment: technically this isn't correct. If you do not need the JS in the header you can enqueue any time before the relevant footer hook is called.

Comment: Thanks guys! I deactivated all plugins and tried the add action hook, too. It was really painfully overall and didn't work unfortunately. So I just saved the newest jquery 3.3.1 locally and changed <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">  </script> through <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jstree/dist/jquery.js';?>"></script> which is my own copy of jquery 3.3.1. Can I just do that in my own template/plugin without worrying that I get in troubles with the already registered version in wordpress(V.1.12.4) on the other pages?

Comment: You may run into issues with the different versions, but there's no guarantee. To be safe, run your jQuery-based scripts in noconflict mode. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @MarkKaplun *can* and *should* are two different things here. Yes, you can run the function above the call to `wp_head()`; no, you shouldn't. Current best practice is to enqueue on a hook.